# Datatable export generic data outside table

Tags: pdf, datatables

I'm trying to add aditional rows during exportation(plz, see attached image), i don't find the right way to do it, please someone tell me  whether or not its possible, since many reports carry parent data that not necesarily appears inside the table. I need the Pdf output with the same format. I'm using yajra datatables for laravel.

```
buttons :[  
             {
              extend: 'pdfHtml5',
              pageSize: 'letter',
              title:  "Informe Asistencia",
              exportOptions: {
                 columns: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ]
              }
             }, 
              ['excel','csv','colvis']
            ],
```

calling the function and drawing table

```
   $.get('{{ url("informes/get_informe_asistencia") }}', 
              {
               'fecha_inicio': fecha_inicio,
               'fecha_fin'   : fecha_fin,
               'numero'      : numero

               },function(resp){
                     console.log(resp);
                     $('.desde').append(fecha_inicio);
                     $('.hasta').append(fecha_fin);
                     $('.nombre').append(resp.informe[1].nombre);
                     $('.ficha').append(resp.informe[1].numero); 

                  dtinforme.clear().draw();
                  dtinforme.rows.add(resp.informe).draw();
                }
```

[missing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nN86.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can export manually.

```
                    text: 'PDF',//title
                    titleAttr: 'Exportar PDF',
                    exportOptions: {
                        ...
                    },
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                                var table = this;
                                dt.clear().draw();
                                dt.rows.add("YOUR DATA").draw();
                                $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.pdfHtml5.action.call(table, e, dt, node, config);
                    }
```

So you need modify your data from with `dt.rows().data().toArray(),dt.settings().init().columns.`

Comment: hello Wilmer, i'm can't make up my mind on how to implement this solution, i get resp from the controller with data requested on json format as edited above, the classes are the ones that i need to fill up outside the datatable and appear on export